# ReSharper: "The build could not be started. There are multiple projects in the solution at..."

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, resharper

When trying to run NUnit tests with ReSharper, the following message appears in a dialog box and the tests are not run:

`The build could not be started. There are multiple projects in the solution at... <name of the csproj file>`

I have this problem with `Resharper 8.2.1`
I have several projects in my solution. Most of the projects are class libraries. One of the projects is a Web Site (not project exactly). Another one is a Web Application. The Web Site and the Web Application projects are located in the same directory. The Web Site is set to be built only in the Release build.

I have this problem only in The Web Application project, when I try to run some embedded tests in this project. I do not have this problem in other (class library) projects.

The problem was in JetBrains' bug tracker, but was closed: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-328627

Perhaps there some workaround?

**Update:**
When I "Project -> Unload Project" on the Web Site, the problem disappears

Comment: Why are you using a web site? Those are very strange, and it doesn't surprise me that ReSharper has problems with them. Many tools do. For instance, you know that web sites don't actually build, right?

Comment: @JohnSaunders, because I inherited the project this way from the previous developer. I doubt I can easily change it. The Web Site project is a copy of DotNetNuke CMS installation, and our extensions are implemented in separate projects.

Comment: Good luck. That's no doubt the reason for the R# problem.

Comment: Restarting the VS helped me

Comment: I have R# 9.1.1 and have the same issue with unit tests. A customer is using Kentico CMS and it does exactly the same thing. It has a Web Site and an MVC project all in the same directory. Using Project -> Unload Project on the Website does allow you to run the unit tests properly from the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (also with 8.2), at least the same error when running my tests through the menu Resharper > Unit Tests > Run All Tests from Solution. But I found the following work around :

Right click on your unit testing project and select Run Unit Tests. this will start running all the tests from the project (from the resharper interface)

Alternatively you can set up you unit testing solution as start up project and from the Resharper menu choose > Unit Tests > Run Unit Tests

Of course you have to do it for each project that has unit tests, but I guess this is acceptable.

Remark: it seems to be a known bug of version 8.2 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-411631
And that rolling back to 8.1 can fix the problem

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this happened after running performance analysis (i.e. profiling) in Visual Studio.

As documented [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-431957), the solution was to remove these lines from the `.sln` file:

```
GlobalSection(Performance) = preSolution
    HasPerformanceSessions = true
EndGlobalSection}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have any changes to your solution file. I encountered this problem after a source control branch change, when Visual Studio held on to a bunch of changes from the previous branch. Not sure exactly what the cause was, but reverting the changes to my sln file fixed the issue.